# Compute small-world coefficients with networkx

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I'd like to compute the small-world coefficients ([omega](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.smallworld.omega.html#networkx-algorithms-smallworld-omega) and [sigma](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.smallworld.sigma.html#networkx.algorithms.smallworld.sigma)) using `networkx`. From the referenced links, it is said that `omega` should range between `-1` and `1`. Furthermore, if `sigma` is greater than 1, it indicates a small-world graph.
Here is my code:

```
# create a small-world graph
import networkx as nx
G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(n=20,k=2,p=0.2)

# compute the coefficients
print(nx.omega(G))
print(nx.sigma(G))
```

It returns `1.05` for `omega` and `nan` for `sigma`:

```
/Users/tiendh/deeplearning/lib/python3.7/site-packages/networkx/algorithms/smallworld.py:301: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  sigma = (C / Cr) / (L / Lr)
nan
```

Clearly, `omega` is not in the range `(-1,1)` and `sigma` cannot be computed. When I increase the rewriting probability (p) to `0.5`, here is the result:

```
>>> G = nx.watts_strogatz_graph(n=20,k=2,p=0.5)
>>> nx.sigma(G)
0.0
>>> nx.omega(G)
1.132464146023468
```

My questions are:

- Are these methods (`nx.omega` and `nx.sigma`) reliable as they do not follow the descriptions?
- For a large graph, these methods are really slow (e.g., if n=2000, it runs forever on my computer). Is there any way to efficiently compute the coefficients?

Comment: found this today myself while trying to understand a bit more about small world graph metrics. Opened an issue about this [here](https://github.com/networkx/networkx/issues/5064) . I also agree about speed. I think its not very well implemented tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Propping this from the grave, but there's now two methods for small world omega and sigma computation:

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.smallworld.omega.html

and

https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.smallworld.sigma.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30883511)